# Wordpress C# User Login

Tags: users, api, password

I have a very basic C# login system first i've work with localhost and basic databasebase username-password but now i want to connect my project to my website which is wordpress then i realize wordpress database is not at all basic they encrypt user passwords.

This is the code of my login system

```
MySqlCommand cmd =
                    new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM member.member WHERE username=@username AND password=@password ;",
                        connection);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", this.TextBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", this.TextBox2.Text);
```

and this is a example password which is 123456

```
$P$B84VsdpgngrtX/Aep0VNW3X1mz8mzJ.
```

But this is 123456 too

```
$P$B9sKzYbWqf.BTewOR7G.4j2.1.7S87/
```

and this

```
$P$BCkM0oYKnu2/M1Xz5BtDBjnLqKOn.4.
```

how can i recode my program and check password true or false?

Comment: WordPress user password is md5 hashed. Your example password will be saved as md5('123456') = e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e

Comment: mines arent then http://prntscr.com/7o5c4u check out all of them 123456 i registered myself

Comment: We don't know what `metroTextBox2` is and does, so we cannot answer that. You have to use the [MD5 class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5(v=vs.110).aspx) somewhere.

Comment: metrotextbox2 is a netframe work it does nothing just a textboxt desing @toscho

Answer (score 0):

In short you want to mach your password with real hash code right.

```
$user = get_user_by( 'login', $username );
if ( $user && wp_check_password( '123456', $user->data->user_pass, $user->ID) )
   echo "password Matched";
else
   echo "Not matched";
```